# Am I correctly deiniting SKScene?

Tags: ios, swift, skscene

I have a particle that I'm adding to a `UIViewController` through an `SKScene`. The following is my `SKScene` code:

```
class MyScene : SKScene {
    private var emitterNode: SKEmitterNode?

    deinit {
        emitterNode?.removeAllActions()
        emitterNode?.removeFromParent()
        self.removeAllChildren()
    }

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let emitterPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyParticle", ofType: "sks")
        emitterNode = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(emitterPath!) as? SKEmitterNode
        emitterNode!.name = "myParticle"
        emitterNode!.targetNode = self.scene
        emitterNode!.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, 15)
        self.addChild(emitterNode!)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I don't have much knowledge on `SKScene`, but I have had a rare error produced inside the `deinit`, on the line `emitterNode?.removeFromParent()`. Is my code correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are overremoving your nodes. Deinit remove the parent of your emitterNode and find you request but there are not other strong references to that node so this goes to cause a crash.

Remove deinit {} method , it's not necessary. Remember that in **Swift** with **ARC** you don't need to use this method, **ARC** will deinit and free up memory for you.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: The reason I added the deinit line was because if I dont, the app crashes in iOS 8. Unfortunately, it doesn't give a reason why it crashed.

Comment: I've some universal apps starting from iOS8 compatibility without use deinit, maybe some particular old library from third parts, are you use some of them?